# cordova project gives unsupported_grant_type error but same works on browser

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I have a ASP.Net WebAPI2 website that has a /token implementing the OWIN token service. This service is working just fine for my website, I am able to use rest clients and get the token as expected both from my PC as well as Android Phone.

however when I call the service from inside my ionic project deployed on my android phone KitKat OS, i get `{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}`. Its on the same wifi so I am able to use a rest client and get the token using that.

here is the angular code that I am using:

```
.service('LoginTokenService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    function getToken(payLoad, fnSuccess, fnError) {
        return $resource("http://192.168.1.104/token", {},
      {
          "getAuthToken": {
              method: "POST",
              isArray: false,
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },

          }
      })
    .getAuthToken(payLoad, fnSuccess, fnError);
    }
    return ({
        getToken: getToken
    });
```

Also on my webapi code I have set the option `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` like below

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        // Mounts the middleware on the provided app with the options configured
        // above
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }
```

Also the `payLoad` contains `UserName='myuser@domain.com', Password='my_password' & grant_type='password'`

as I am relatively new to ionic and cardova I was wondering if anyone has encountered the similar issue.

Comment: I suggest that you put your edit in as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the issue. on my Website, i used `$.param(payload)` to send login info to the /token service, but as JQuery was not available in the ionic by default, I removed that.

I have now used the `$httpParamSerializerJQLike(payLoad)` to serialize the payload and its working now..